# Excel array formulas to make pairs

Tags: excel

Suppose I have two array formulas with the following:

```
{A,B,C}
{3,2,1}
```

What formula can be used to produce the following output in the cell:

```
A-3, B-2, C-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Office 365 Excel:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,{"A","B","C"}&"-"&{3,2,1})
```

[image]

Comment: Was plugging the two arrays in as separate arguments. Learned something here. Thank you